# Microsoft System Center Virtual Machine Manager without Active Directory

Tags: virtual-machine, active-directory, hyper-v

In our work network, we are not using Active Directory. We have Microsoft Action Pack, and a copy of System Center Essentials came with the Action Pack. I attempted to install it to use Virtual Machine Manager to manage a Microsoft Hyper-V server, but it is not allowing me to install because I am not on a domain (AD).

Is there a workaround to this issue, or am I required to register in AD to install this product?

Comment: If you have the Action Pack, what reason do you have to not use a domain?  I doubt SCVMM will authenticate connections without it.

Comment: Most of our work is done outside our office, and we didn't see a need for the trouble. At least that's what I think. I didn't set up the LAN.

Comment: I don't understand that, as it makes things a lot easier.  Just set up a domain.  Your Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise licence allows four virtual machines on one computer.  There are some things to watch out for when setting up a virtualised DC, and also if you add the Hyper-V host to the domain, but this is another question.

Comment: Well, it really doesn't matter if it's better or not, that wasn't what I was asking. I'm not the Microsoft guy in our company, so it's not my choice. I wanted to know how I could get around this software issue, and it looks like it's not possible. I gave it back to the MS guy, so I'll see what happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. An active directory domain at windows 2003 functional level or above is required for SCVMM.

If you want the official word from Microsoft: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc764275.aspx
"Before installing the VMM server, you must join the computer to a domain in Active Directory."